# How to auto apply and remove border in Google sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

```
 function onEdit(e) {
  var sheetName = "RemoveBorder";
  var range = e.range;
  var sheet = range.getSheet();

  if (
    sheet.getName() === sheetName &&
    range.getRow() >= 2 &&
    range.getRow() <= sheet.getLastRow() &&
    range.getColumn() >= 1 &&
    range.getColumn() <= 4
  ) {
    var startColumn = range.getColumn();
    var endColumn = startColumn + 3;
    var row = range.getRow();
    var adjacentRange = sheet.getRange(row, startColumn, 1, endColumn - startColumn + 1);

    if (range.getValue() === "") {
      adjacentRange.setBorder(null);
    } else {
      var border = true;
      var style = SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID;
      var color = "black";
      adjacentRange.setBorder(border, border, border, border, border, border, color, style);
    }
  }
}
```

I want that if I delete the value of A2 cell, then the border on its right side should also be removed automatically. This should work on the below cell as well.

Comment: Please provide an example data showing the position before and after; and also show how `This should work on the below cell as well.`

Comment: `range` is one of the [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit), so `var range = e.range;` merely creates a variable that enables easy referencing of the "range" Event Objects. It does NOT define a range in the normal sense. Because of this, the script is failing on `if (range.getValue() === "") {`. OTOG, `var edittedRange = sheet.getRange(range.getRow(),range.getColumn())` will define the range for the edited cell, and you could use `if (edittedRange.isBlank() === true) {` to test if the edited cell is blank.

Comment: The script fails on `adjacentRange.setBorder(null);`. `setBorder` requires arguments for top, left, bottom, right, vertical, and horizontal where true (on), false (off) and null (no change). So, the revised command might look like: `adjacentRange.setBorder(null,false,null,false,false,null)`.

Comment: I want that if I delete the value of A2 cell, then the border on its right side should also be removed automatically. This should work on the below cell as well.

Comment: `<= sheet.getLastRow()` will make the script apply to any row, not just rows 2 and 3. So do you mean "if I delete the value of A2 cell, A3, or any row below, then the border on its right side should also be removed automatically. "

Comment: Only border is being applied in this

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your comment. Regarding `This should work on the below cell as well.` Rather than "as well", would you please describe your detailed objective for the cell below as a specific requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function onEdit(e) {

  // Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e)) // DEBUG
    
  var sheetName = "RemoveBorder";
  var range = e.range;
  var sheet = range.getSheet();
  var edittedRange = sheet.getRange(range.getRow(),range.getColumn())
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: edited range = "+edittedRange.getA1Notation()) 
  if (
    sheet.getName() === sheetName &&
    range.getRow() >= 2 &&
    range.getRow() <= sheet.getLastRow() &&
    range.getColumn() >= 1 &&
    range.getColumn() <= 4
  ) 
  {

    // Logger.log("DEBUG: sheet = "+sheet.getName()+", row = "+range.getRow()+", column= "+range.getColumn())
    var startColumn = range.getColumn();
    var endColumn = startColumn + 3;
    var row = range.getRow();
    var adjacentRange = sheet.getRange(row, startColumn, 1, endColumn - startColumn + 1);
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: adjacentRange = "+sheet.getRange(row, startColumn, 1, endColumn - startColumn + 1).getA1Notation())
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: is thr editted cell empty? : "+edittedRange.isBlank())
    if (edittedRange.isBlank() === true) {
      adjacentRange.setBorder(null,false,null,false,false,null)
    } else {
      var border = true;
      var style = SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID;
      var color = "black";
      adjacentRange.setBorder(border, border, border, border, border, border, color, style);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: if i delete A2 or below cell value then border not removing automatically.

Comment: Works for me. Please share you spreadsheet.

Comment: @AshokKumar I understand that the script is not meeting your expectations but I do not understand **exactly** what aspect of your expectations are not met. Your comment that `then border not removing automatically` is vague and unclear; your sample image is also unclear - is this the actual or desired output; what did you do in the spreadsheet to create this. Would you please provide example data showing the position before and after; and also show how this "should work on the below cell as well".